# Python module not found with sudo in github action

Tags: python, pip, github-actions, sudo, coverage.py

I wanted to use [coveragepy](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy) combine to seperate .coverage files into one.

For that I installed python and the coverage module via pip, afterwards then running this command. `python -m coverage combine .coverage-*`. That should work and does, but aparrently requires either root or for the user to own the directory. So I decided to use sudo within the github action, since I read that it's passwordless.

But when running the installed module with sudo in front of the command it says `/usr/bin/python: No module named coverage`.

This is the part of my workflow responsible for the actions explained above:

```
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"

      - name: Install coverage
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install coverage

      - name: Listing all items in data directory (Testing)
        run: ls -Al ./docker/data/coverage

      - name: Merge coverage reports
        working-directory: ./docker/data/coverage
        run: sudo python -m coverage combine .coverage-*
```

running the `sudo python -m coverage combine .coverage-*` on my local machine works just fine.

Is there any way I can get python to recognise that, that module exists and is installed or is there maybe any other workaround I could use?

Comment: Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question along with the commands that work fine on your local machine. Thanks!

Comment: If you use `sudo` then Python accesses a different set of packages (`site-packages`) doesn't it? What was more concretely the issue (error message if any) when running without sudo (it is not described in the question)? Also I would suggest to use a virtual environment to improve the ease of reproducibility.

Comment: Well yes, apparently, I just didn't realise that. This is the error when running without sudo `Couldn't use data file '/home/runner/work/repo/repo/docker/data/coverage/.coverage': unable to open database file`. And when it comes to virtual environments, I don't know much about them nor how exactly im suppossed to use them in this kind of situation. But I might look into it if you could elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect pip is installing coverage to the user directory.  If you must run the command with sudo, try running the pip install with sudo as well.

Comment: All right will give it a try, thank you